# User 'X\y' failed to create external configuration store at 'D:\Hyper-V':

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I have a Hyper-V server which has served me well, so far.  It's been in a workgroup until recently, and has hosted four machines.  I hadn't used it for a while and decided to join it to my new domain.  I also had to apply a load of patches.

Now, I'm trying to create a new machine.  I've already created the hard disk and when I try to create the VM I'm getting a window which says:

> The server encountered an error while creating DomainSql1.
>
> The operation failed.
>
> Failed to create external configuration store at 'D:\Hyper-V': General access denied error (Virtual machine ID 0x80070005)

and in the event log:

> Log Name:      Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-VMMS-Admin
>
> Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-VMMS
>
> Date:          22/07/2012 06:53:09
>
> Event ID:      13000
>
> Task Category: None
>
> Level:         Error
>
> Keywords:
>
> User:          SYSTEM
>
> Computer:      Computer.Domain.local
>
> Description: User 'DOMAIN\Administrator' failed to create external configuration store at 'D:\Hyper-V': General access denied error (Virtual machine ID 0x80070005)

I've had a search and found one problem which mentions symbolic links but that doesn't seem to apply to me as I can see the symbolic link in "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Hyper-V\Virtual Machines" and the folder path its pointing to get created at "D:\Hyper-V Domain\DomainSQL1\Virtual Machines" but it's empty - no XML file is created.  The Virtual Machines identity has the following permissions on the Virtual Machines folder:

- List folder/read data
- Read attributes
- Read extended attributes
- Create files/wroi

Comment: Have you tried logging in as a local user (local admin) and creating the machine? Does that work?

Comment: Does your computer itself have access on the folder? I belive it should have been created with the sym link but try just for testing giving {compname}$ read access to the same folder and see if that gets it. If that works you might need to do a storage migration to force the permissions on the folder to rebuild.